# Vaadin 8 Treegrid always fetching all rows though using AbstractBackEndHierarchicalDataProvider for lazyloading

Tags: vaadin8

Hello I am using `TreeGrid (Vaadin 8.6.3)` with `AbstractBackEndHierarchicalDataProvider` for lazy loading

I have overridden `fetchChildrenFromBackEnd`, `getChildCount` and `hasChildren` methods.

My total row count in db is 400.

My Issue is whenever the Treegrid is rendered, it is fetching all 400 rows at one show (the offset value is 0 and limit value is 400). I have not overridden the default limit anywhere.

The first call to `getChildCount` returns 400, `fetchChildrenFromBackEnd` always has the offset value 0 and limit 400 .

Answer (score 1):

Vaadin said that it's not a bug but a missing features!! ;-(

So, you cannot use treegrid for a large dataset.

https://github.com/vaadin/framework/issues/11447